# Переадресация при запросе информации о аудиозаписи на Newgrounds

Tags: python, веб-программирование, api, requests, redirect

Хотел написать себе плеер для Newgrounds. Выяснил, что при нажатии на кнопку проигрывания идёт запрос на `https://www.newgrounds.com/audio/load/<id аудиозаписи>/<тип аудиозаписи>`, а ответом является JSON структура.

Но когда я пытаюсь сделать это вручную (см. код ниже), то идёт ридерект на страницу прослушивания.

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.newgrounds.com/audio")
cookies = r.cookies

r = requests.get("https://www.newgrounds.com/audio/load/1121405/3", cookies=cookies)
print(r.text)
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: Куки, реферер, API-токены?

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо! Нужно было указать `'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'` в заголовок запроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно в заголовоке запроса указать `'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'`.

```
import requests

headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
r = requests.get('https://www.newgrounds.com/audio/load/1121269/3', headers=headers)

print(r.text)
```